# Display blog posts on different sections on the index page with Node.Js, Express and EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I am new to node.js and to programming in general, so this question may sound stupid to experts, but I am trying to build a simple blog app. The part I’m struggling with is how to render data to my views. I want to be able to display posts based on categories (sports, fashion, news etc.) on different sections on the index page, similar to what a news site like www.newyorker.com would have on their home page. I’m using express, mongoose and ejs as my views engine.

Thanks!

```
--------

This is my app.js file:

var bodyParser          = require("body-parser"),
    methodOverride      = require("method-override"),
    expressSanitizer    = require("express-sanitizer"),
    mongoose            = require("mongoose"),
    express             = require("express"),
    app                 = express();


// APP CONFIG
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/tnm_blog_app");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(expressSanitizer());
app.use(methodOverride("_method"));




// MONGOOSE/MODEL CONFIG

var blogSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    image: String,
    body: String,
    category: String, 
    author: String, 
    created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var Blog = mongoose.model("Blog", blogSchema); 

// ROUTES

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.redirect("/index"); 
});

// INDEX ROUTE

app.get("/index", function(req, res){
    Blog.find({}, function(err, blogs){
        if(err){
            console.log("ERROR!");
        } else {
            res.render("index", {blogs: blogs});
        }
    });
});

// NEW ROUTE
app.get("/index/new", function(req, res){
    res.render("new");
});

// CREATE ROUTE

app.post("/index", function(req, res){
Blog.create(req.body.blog, function(err, newBlog){
    if(err){
        res.render("new");
    } else {
        res.redirect("/index");
    }
});
});


// SHOW ROUTE

app.get("/index/:id", function(req, res){

   Blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundBlog){
       if(err){
           res.redirect("/index");
       } else {
           res.render("show", {blog: foundBlog});
       }
   });
});

// EDIT ROUTE

app.get("/index/:id/edit", function(req, res){
    Blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundBlog){
        if(err){
            res.redirect("/index");
        } else {
            res.render("edit", {blog: foundBlog});
        }
    });
});

// UPDATE ROUTE

app.put("/index/:id", function(req, res){
    req.body.blog.body = req.sanitize(req.body.blog.body);
    Blog.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.blog, function(err, updatedBlog){
      if(err){
          res.redirect("/index");
      }  else {
          res.redirect("/index/" + req.params.id);
      }
    });
});

// DELETE ROUTE
app.delete("/index/:id", function(req, res){
    Blog.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, function(err){
        if(err){
            res.redirect("/index");
        } else {
            res.redirect("/index");
        }
    });
});


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("SERVER IS RUNNING!");
});

This is my index.ejs file
------------------------
<% include ./partials/header %>

<div class="ui main text container">
    <div class="ui huge header">The TNM Blog</div>
    <div class="ui top  attached segment">
        <div class="ui divided items">
            <% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src="<%= blog.image %>" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="content">
                         <a class="header" href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>"><%=blog.title%></a>
                         <div class="meta">
                             <span><%= blog.created.toDateString() %></span>
                         </div>
                         <div class="description">
                             <p><%- blog.body.substring(0, 100) %>...</p>
                         </div>
                         <div class="extra">
                             <a class="ui floated basic violet button" href="/index/<%= blog._id %>">
                                 Read More
                                 <i class="right chevron icon"></i>
                             </a>
                         </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <% }) %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<% include ./partials/footer %>

This is my show template

<% include ./partials/header %>
<div class="ui main text container segment">
    <div class="ui huge header"><%= blog.title %></div>
    <div class="ui top attached ">
        <div class="item">
            <img class="ui centered rounded image" src="<%= blog.image %>" >
            <div class="content">
                <span><%= blog.created.toDateString() %></span>
            </div>
            <div class="description">
                <p><%- blog.body %></p>
            </div>
            <a class="ui orange basic button" href="/index/<%= blog._id %>/edit">Edit</a>
            <form id="delete" action="/index/<%= blog._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
                <button class="ui red basic button">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<% include ./partials/footer %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to tell the render engine what categories the posts need to be filtered into and then put a different forEach loop into the ejs template based on each category. I'm sure you can pull the categories in a more clever way but I'm just hardcoding an array of strings for example here:

```
// INDEX ROUTE

app.get("/index", function(req, res){
    Blog.find({}, function(err, blogs){
        if(err){
            console.log("ERROR!");
        } else {
            var categories = ['news', 'shopping']
            res.render("index", {blogs: blogs, categories: categories});
        }
    });
});
```

Then in your ejs template you can do a forEach category and then show blogs which meet that category

```
<% categories.forEach(function(category){ %>
    <% blogs.forEach(function(blog){ %>
        <% if(blog.category == category) { %>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="<%= blog.image %>" >
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <a class="header" href="/blogs/<%= blog._id %>"><%=blog.title%></a>
                <div class="meta">
                    <span><%= blog.created.toDateString() %></span>
                </div>
                <div class="description">
                    <p><%- blog.body.substring(0, 100) %>...</p>
                </div>
                <div class="extra">
                    <a class="ui floated basic violet button" href="/index/<%= blog._id %>">
                        Read More
                        <i class="right chevron icon"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% } %>
    <% }) %>
<% }) %>
```

The above will definitely work but is a little inefficient so I would also encourage you to try and see if ejs supports a JS filter function

```
<% blogs.filter(b => b.category==category).forEach(function(blog){ %>
```